# Insert returns -1 with SQLite

Tags: android

I have been struggling with this for hours. My SQLite insert always returns -1 ...

Here is my code from the main activity in one file that calls my db code in another file:

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
    jobsdb = new NotifyJobsDBAdapter(this);
    jobsdb.open();

    currentjobid = 1;
    currentjob = new Job(currentjobid, "Starting Tele Num", "Starting Text Msg");
    currentjobid = jobsdb.insertJob(currentjob);
   // this last statement returns -1
}
```

This is my db adaptor code in another file:

public class NotifyJobsDBAdapter {

```
private static final String DB_NAME = "notifyjobsdb";
private static final String DB_TABLE = "notifyjobs";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private final Context ctx;

// Database column names
private static final String JOB_ID = "jobid";
private static final String JOB_TELE = "contactnumber";
private static final String JOB_TEXT = "textmessage";

private SQLiteDatabase notifyjobsdb;
private NotifyJobsDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private boolean openness;
private boolean err;
private boolean err0;
private int cnt;
private int i1;
private String s1;
private String s2;
private static String s3;
private int res;
private SQLiteException ex0;
private SQLiteException ex1;

private static class NotifyJobsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_TABLE +
        " (+ " + JOB_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        JOB_TELE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        JOB_TEXT + "TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private static final String DATABASE_UPGRADE = 
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notifyjobs ";

    public NotifyJobsDatabaseHelper(Context _context) {
        super(_context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_UPGRADE);
                }

}

public NotifyJobsDBAdapter(Context _context) {
    this.ctx = _context;
}

public void open() { 
    dbHelper = new NotifyJobsDatabaseHelper(ctx);
    try { notifyjobsdb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
        ex0 = ex;
    }

}  

public void close() {
    notifyjobsdb.close();
}
```

// this is my problem method

```
public int insertJob(Job _job) {
    ContentValues newJobValues = new ContentValues();
    newJobValues.put(JOB_ID, _job.getjobid());
    newJobValues.put(JOB_TELE, _job.gettelenum());
    newJobValues.put(JOB_TEXT, _job.gettextmsg());
    notifyjobsdb.beginTransaction();
    // res is always returned a -1
    try {
    res = (int) notifyjobsdb.insertOrThrow(DB_TABLE, null, newJobValues);
    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
        ex1 = ex;
    }

    notifyjobsdb.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
    close();
    return res;
```

Here, res is always -1 and the debugger shows the detailmessage for ex1 as

"no such table: notifyjobs: , while compiling: INSERT INTO notifyjobs(contactnumber, textmessage, jobid) VALUES(?, ?, ?);

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to name the primary id field of your tables "_id" so Android will know where to bind the id field of your tables. So I suggest you try to name your ID columns "_id" instead of "jobid".

Also, I suggest not to use transactions where you do only one operation (you can later on decide to wrap multiple insert into a transaction).

Comment: Why did you decided that it is necessary to name primary id field as "_id"? Any reference?

Comment: private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_TABLE +
   " ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
   JOB_TELE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
   JOB_TEXT + "TEXT NOT NULL);";

Comment: And now I do not get -1, but I get the same exception each time?

Comment: @Konstantin: from what I understood in the SDK and the various examples, it is a convention. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID and http://markmail.org/message/7dslzyn7elk73wkt: "The _id is named with an underscore convention used in a number of places inside the Android SDK and helps keep a track of state."

Comment: @MLW: can you give the Exception message?

Comment: I have it running now, thanks a lot. I actually had 2 problems as everyone sees here.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your DATABASE_CREATE statement, thus your table was not created. And that's why you're getting the error message. Try fixing your create statement (remove plus sign after opening bracket):

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_TABLE +
    " (" + JOB_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
    JOB_TELE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    JOB_TEXT + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Comment: You are right, that is weird and I am wondering if that was my cut and paste. Would the above not compile? Anyway, good spotting. I am still getting that ex1 exception now, but not the -1 returned.

Comment: Damn, you're right. And before TEXT as well. Fixed the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your create statement is wrong. This is the correct one:

   ```
   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_TABLE +
   " (" + JOB_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
   JOB_TELE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
   JOB_TEXT + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
   ```
2. If you're trying to insert a row that does not match a constraint (e.g. an already existing primary key or null values for JOB_TELE/JOB_TEXT column), you'll get an exception.